# How to get individual plot percentages on facet wrap plots in r

Tags: r, ggplot2

New to R, apologies in advance. I have run the following code to get separate plots showing the percentage of proportion of Injury_Areas for each Occupation_Proper.

```
SelectOccupation_InjuryAreas %>% 
  group_by(Occupation_Proper) %>% 
  mutate(prop = counnt / sum(counnt)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(Injury_Area, prop)) +
  ylab('prop')  +
  geom_bar(stat="identity") +
  scale_y_continuous(labels=percent) + 
  facet_wrap(~ Occupation_Proper,ncol=2)+
  geom_col(aes(fill = Occupation_Proper), position = "dodge") +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, hjust = 1)) +
  geom_text(aes(label = scales::percent(prop), 
                y = prop, 
                group = Occupation_Proper),
            position = position_dodge(width = 0.9),
            vjust = 1.5)
```

I would like to show the percentage of each Injury_Area as a percentage of the total of all Injury_Area for each Occupation_Proper separately. The code that I ran for some reason is displaying the Injury_Area percentages as a percentage of all of the plots combined instead of displaying the percentages for each plot separately (e.g. percentage for each plot separately should add up to 100), see picture of plots [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/INX3i.jpg). How do I get percentages of proportions for each plot separately? Thank you!

My data is as follows (using R Studio so hopefully this is the correct way to display.

```
structure(list(Occupation_Proper = c("HTO", "HTO", "HTO", "HTO", 
"HTO", "HTO", "HTO", "HTO", "HTO", "HTO", "HTO", "HTO", "HTO", 
"HTO", "HTO", "HTO", "HTO", "HTO", "Bl", "Bl", "Bl", "Bl", "Bl", 
"Bl", "Bl", "Bl", "Bl", "Bl", "Bl", "Cb", "Cb", "Cb", "Cb", "Cb", 
"Cb", "Cb", "Cb", "Cb", "Cb", "Cb", "Cb", "CrO", "EO", "EO", 
"EO", "EO", "EO", "EO", "EO", "EO", "EO", "EO", "EO", "EO", "EO", 
"EO", "EO", "L", "L", "L", "TR", "TR", "TR", "TR", "TR", "TR", 
"TR", "TR", "WH", "WH", "WH", "WH", "WH", "WH", "WH", "WH", "WH", 
"WH", "WH", "WH"), Injury_Area = c("Back", "Neck", "Hand", "Head", 
"Face", "Arm", "Leg", "Foot", "Knee", "Chest", "Eye", "Ear", 
"Ribs", "Throat_Tongue", "Other", "Hip", "Buttock_Pelvis", "Torso", 
"Neck", "Hand", "Head", "Arm", "Leg", "Knee", "Eye", "Ear", "Other", 
"Hip", "Torso", "Neck", "Hand", "Head", "Arm", "Leg", "Foot", 
"Knee", "Eye", "Other", "Hip", "Buttock_Pelvis", "Torso", "Knee", 
"Neck", "Hand", "Head[", "Face", "Arm", "Leg", "Foot", "Knee", 
"Torso_Buttock", "Eye", "Ear", "Spill", "Other", "Buttock_Pelvis", 
"Torso", "Arm", "Eye", "Other", "Neck", "Hand", "Face", "Arm", 
"Knee", "Eye", "Ear", "Hip", "Hand", "Head", "Face", "Arm", "Leg", 
"Knee", "Eye", "Ear", "Other", "Hip", "Buttock_Pelvis", "Torso"
), counnt = c(4, 30, 20, 17, 15, 18, 32, 6, 13, 5, 12, 9, 2, 
3, 50, 5, 6, 3, 2, 1, 1, 2, 7, 7, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 4, 7, 2, 5, 
16, 1, 5, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 2, 14, 18, 6, 7, 19, 14, 3, 6, 1, 5, 
4, 2, 26, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 11, 2, 7, 1, 1, 5, 1, 12, 1, 3, 8, 
2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1)), row.names = c(NA, -80L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Your code *should* be doing that. My best guess is that you are accidentally using `plyr::mutate` (which doesn't know about groups) rather than `dplyr::mutate` (which does). Try specifying `dplyr::mutate` and your plot should work. In the future, be careful not to load `plyr` after `dplyr` (there's a big warning that prints if you do this).

Comment: Let me know if the solution below works for you and don't forget to accept the answer if it is the one you like best.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
df %>% 
    rename(count = counnt) %>% 
    group_by(Occupation_Proper) %>% 
    mutate(percent = (count/sum(count) * 100)) %>%
    ggplot(aes(x = Injury_Area, y = percent, fill = Occupation_Proper)) +
    geom_bar(stat="identity") +
    facet_wrap(~ Occupation_Proper, ncol=2) +
    theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, hjust = 1, vjust = 0.5)) +
    geom_text(aes(label = paste(sprintf("%.1f", percent), "%", sep=""), 
                  y = percent+7.5))
```

[image]